# How can I convert Flickr's "date_create" and "date_update" into an NSDate using NSDateFormatter?

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, flickr

I'm using [ObjectiveFlickr](http://code.google.com/p/objectiveflickr/) to retrieve a collection of photos from Flickr. The dates are returned as strings like "`1309695647`".

What are these numbers? Milliseconds? I can't figure out how to define a date format to convert them into `NSDate` objects using `NSDateFormatter` :(

The [Flickr documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getList.html) doesn't help and I can't find anything on google :(

Comment: Do you know what date that should actually represent? `NSDate` has the method `- (id)initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)seconds` could be a good place to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high probability is that these dates are regular timestamps (unsigned int, number of seconds since January 1, 1970). See below:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.dates.html

> **Posted dates**
>
> The 'posted' date represents the time
>   at which the photo was uploaded to
>   Flickr. This is set at the time of
>   upload.
>
> The posted date is always passed
>   around as a unix timestamp, which is
>   an unsigned integer specifying the
>   number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970
>   GMT.
>
> All posted dates are passed around in
>   GMT and it's up to the application
>   provider to format them using the
>   relevant viewer's timezone.